# What is the actual direction of real current in an A.C. generator? From the North pole to the South?

Tags: current, ac, generator

I see diagrams of a current being generated in a loop or square-ish section of wire that is rotating between two magnetic poles... a north on one side and a south on the other...

BUT, the current direction is sometimes portrayed as being from the North to the South, and other times vice versa...

I assume this has to do with some diagrams still going by 'conventional current' instead of true current...

Comment: What do you mean by **still** going by conventional current?

Comment: Hint to your actual question: suppose you change the direction you wound the wire loop...

Comment: The right hand rule applies.

Comment: Left- and right-hand rules explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors).

Comment: Hint:  AC stands for A.l.t.e.r.n.a.t.i.n.g Current.

Comment: Current does not flow North to South, or South to North, that's what the magnetic field does. Current flows at right angles to the field.

Answer (score 2):

Look up 'Fleming's Right Hand Rule'.

The direction of current induced in the conductor is decided by the direction of the magnetic field and the direction of movement of the conductor.